# Automated cross-compilation failing at rosdep install step

Tags: ros2, rosdep, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to [cross-compile](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Cross-compilation/#automated-cross-compilation) **ros2 crystal** core for **Ubuntu 18.04 armv7**, building on Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64:

See the end of my question for my custom files.

During the build of the contained docker, I have this failure while trying to do:

```
RUN rosdep init
RUN rosdep update
RUN rosdep install --from-paths src 
    --ignore-src \
    --rosdistro crystal -y \
    --skip-keys "console_bridge \
        fastcdr \
        fastrtps \
        libopensplice67 \
        libopensplice69 \
        rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 \
        urdfdom_headers"
```

as rosdep trying to download these (unwanted) dependencies:

```
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-tf2] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-tf2-eigen] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-tf2-geometry-msgs] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-tf2-ros] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-kdl-parser] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-urdf] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-robot-state-publisher] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-demo-nodes-py] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-angles] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-depthimage-to-laserscan] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-joy] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-pcl-conversions] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-rviz2] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-rviz-default-plugins] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-teleop-twist-joy] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-teleop-twist-keyboard] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-composition] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-demo-nodes-cpp] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-demo-nodes-cpp-native] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-dummy-map-server] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-dummy-robot-bringup] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-dummy-sensors] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-image-tools] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-intra-process-demo] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-lifecycle] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-logging-demo] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-pendulum-control] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-topic-monitor] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-tlsf] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-tlsf-cpp] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-action-client] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-action-server] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-client] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-composition] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-publisher] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-service] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-subscriber] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclcpp-minimal-timer] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclpy-executors] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclpy-minimal-client] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclpy-minimal-publisher] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclpy-minimal-service] failed
  apt: command [apt-get install -y ros-crystal-examples-rclpy-minimal-subscriber] failed
```

Using the -r option seems to be a workaround but i would like to understand why rosdep is trying to find and install these dependencies, not necessary according to [ROS REP 2001](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2001.html#ros-core) ?

Contents of files:

`ros2_core.install`:

```
- git:
    local-name: ament/ament_cmake
    uri: https://github.com/ament/ament_cmake.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/ament_cmake_ros
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/ament_cmake_ros.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ament/ament_index
    uri: https://github.com/ament/ament_index.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ament/ament_lint
    uri: https://github.com/ament/ament_lint.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ament/ament_package
    uri: https://github.com/ament/ament_package.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros/class_loader
    uri: https://github.com/ros/class_loader.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/common_interfaces
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/console_bridge_vendor
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/console_bridge_vendor.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: eProsima/Fast-CDR
    uri: https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-CDR.git
    version: v1.0.8
- git:
    local-name: eProsima/Fast-RTPS
    uri: https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-RTPS.git
    version: b48ce9d2fba6fc94e756da01c58b72f2ad848238
- git:
    local-name: ament/googletest
    uri: https://github.com/ament/googletest.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/launch
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/launch.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/libyaml_vendor
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/libyaml_vendor.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: osrf/osrf_pycommon
    uri: https://github.com/osrf/osrf_pycommon.git
    version: master
- git:
    local-name: osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp
    uri: https://github.com/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros/pluginlib
    uri: https://github.com/ros/pluginlib.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/poco_vendor
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/poco_vendor.git
    version: master
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rcl
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rcl.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rcl_interfaces
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rcl_logging
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rclcpp
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rclpy
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rclpy.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: rcutils
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rcutils.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rmw
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rmw.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rmw_connext
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rmw_connext.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rmw_fastrtps
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rmw_fastrtps.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rmw_implementation
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rmw_implementation.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rmw_opensplice
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rmw_opensplice.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/ros2cli
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros/ros_environment
    uri: https://github.com/ros/ros_environment.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl_dds
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_dds.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl_defaults
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_defaults.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl_python
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_python.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl_typesupport
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl_typesupport_connext
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_connext.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice.git
    version: master
- git:
    local-name: ros2/tinyxml2_vendor
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/tinyxml2_vendor.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ament/uncrustify_vendor
    uri: https://github.com/ament/uncrustify_vendor.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: ros2/unique_identifier_msgs
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/unique_identifier_msgs.git
    version: crystal
- git:
    local-name: variants
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/variants.git
    version: crystal
```

`Dockerfile_cc`:

```
# Copyright (c) 2018, ARM Limited.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

FROM ubuntu:bionic

# Set timezone
RUN echo 'Etc/UTC' > /etc/timezone && \
    ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y tzdata && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 1. Install development tools
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    lsb-core \
    bash-completion

# Download the Cross-compiler for aarch64/arm and qemu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    qemu-user-static \
    g++-aarch64-linux-gnu \
    g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf

# ROS2 tools
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip

RUN python3 -m pip install -U \
    colcon-common-extensions \
    rosdep \
    vcstool \
    rosinstall-generator

# Install Docker
RUN apt-get install -y \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce

# 2. Download ROS2 src
ENV CC_WS /root/cc_ws
ARG ROS2_VERSION=release-latest

WORKDIR $CC_WS/ros2_ws
RUN mkdir src
COPY ros2_core.install .
RUN vcs import --repos --recursive src < ros2_core.install
WORKDIR $CC_WS/ros2_ws/src
COPY ./cross_compile ./cross_compile

WORKDIR $CC_WS
run mkdir qemu-user-static
RUN cp /usr/bin/qemu-*-static qemu-user-static

ENTRYPOINT ["ros2_ws/src/cross_compile/entry_point.sh"]
CMD ["bash"]
```

`Dockerfile_ubuntu_arm`:

```
# Copyright (c) 2018, ARM Limited.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

ARG ARM_ARCH=arm32v7
FROM ${ARM_ARCH}/ubuntu:bionic

COPY ./qemu-user-static/* /usr/bin/
COPY ./ros2_ws/src /ros2_ws/src

# Set timezone
RUN echo 'Etc/UTC' > /etc/timezone && \
    ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC /etc/localtime && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y tzdata && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
    pkg-config \
    lsb-release \
    curl \
    gfortran \
    libpcre3 \
    libpcre3-dev \
    bash-completion \
    dirmngr \
    gnupg2

# ROS2 dependencies
RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    git \
    wget

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

RUN curl http://repo.ros2.org/repos.key | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,armhf] http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main \
    `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y \
    python3-colcon-common-extensions \
    python3-pip \
    python3-rosdep

RUN python3 -m pip install -U \
    argcomplete \
    flake8 \
    flake8-blind-except \
    flake8-builtins \
    flake8-class-newline \
    flake8-comprehensions \
    flake8-deprecated \
    flake8-docstrings \
    flake8-import-order \
    flake8-quotes \
    pytest-repeat \
    pytest-rerunfailures

RUN python3 -m pip install -U \
    pytest \
    pytest-cov \
    pytest-runner \
    setuptools

RUN apt install --no-install-recommends -y \
    libasio-dev \
    libtinyxml2-dev

WORKDIR /ros2_ws
RUN rosdep init
RUN rosdep update
RUN rosdep install --from-paths src 
    --ignore-src \
    --rosdistro crystal -y \
    --skip-keys "console_bridge \
        fastcdr \
        fastrtps \
        libopensplice67 \
        libopensplice69 \
        rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 \
        urdfdom_headers"

WORKDIR /
RUN apt-get install -y symlinks
RUN symlinks -rc .
```

`entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copyright (c) 2018, ARM Limited.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

# Exit on error
set -e

# 3. Prepare the sysroot
if [ ! -d "$CC_WS/sysroot_docker" ]; then
    # Build sysroot image
    docker build -t arm_ros2:latest -f ./ros2_ws/src/cross_compile/sysroot/Dockerfile_ubuntu_arm .
    docker run --name arm_sysroot arm_ros2:latest

    # Export sysroot image
    docker container export -o sysroot_docker.tar arm_sysroot
    mkdir sysroot_docker

    tar -C sysroot_docker -xf sysroot_docker.tar lib usr etc

    # Remove docker container
    docker rm arm_sysroot
fi

# 4. Build
# Export toolchain-file variable
export TARGET_ARCH=armhf
export TARGET_TRIPLE=arm-linux-gnueabihf

export CC=/usr/bin/$TARGET_TRIPLE-gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/$TARGET_TRIPLE-g++
export CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/$TARGET_TRIPLE-

export SYSROOT=$CC_WS/sysroot_docker
export PYTHON_SOABI=cpython-36m-$TARGET_TRIPLE
export ROS2_INSTALL_PATH=$CC_WS/ros2_ws/install

# Hack to find Poco
## This is temporarily required to find the Poco libraries on the SYSROOT.
## The exported target comming with the pre-build binaries has a hard-coded
## path to "/usr/lib/<arch>/libz.so" and "/usr/lib/<arch>/libpcre.so"
ln -s `pwd`/sysroot_docker/lib/$TARGET_TRIPLE/libz.so.1 /usr/lib/$TARGET_TRIPLE/libz.so
ln -s `pwd`/sysroot_docker/lib/$TARGET_TRIPLE/libpcre.so.3 /usr/lib/$TARGET_TRIPLE/libpcre.so

# Ignore some packages
touch \
    ros2_ws/src/variants/desktop/COLCON_IGNORE \
    ros2_ws/src/variants/base/COLCON_IGNORE

# Trigger a build
colcon build --merge-install \
    --cmake-force-configure \
    --cmake-args \
        -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON \
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="$(pwd)/src/cross_compile/cmake-toolchains/generic_linux.cmake" \
        -DSECURITY=ON \
        -DFORCE_BUILD_VENDOR_PKG=ON
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320156/automated-cross-compilation-failing-at-rosdep-install-step/) by [William Bulle](https://answers.ros.org/users/40424/william-bulle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:
Can you clarify whether you've seen [ros2/cross_compile](https://github.com/ros2/cross_compile)?

---

Edit: ah, I guess you did. Would appear the Dockerfiles are from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to have the `variants` repository in your `.install` file:

```
- git:
    local-name: variants
    uri: https://github.com/ros2/variants.git
    version: crystal
```

That repository contains package manifests for *all* ROS 2 variants (so: `ros_base`, `ros_core` and `desktop`). Those are probably pulling all those additional dependencies in.

I'm not sure, but I don't believe `variants` is part of any ROS 2 variant, so would you know how that entry got added to the list?

---

Edit:

> I generated my `.install` with
>
> ```
> rosinstall_generator ros_core --rosdistro crystal --upstream-development --deps > ros2_core.install
> ```

why do you add `--upstream-development` there? That will use the *source* repositories for all entries, instead of the *release* repositories. It will also cause complete checkouts of entire repositories instead of just one specific package.

That is most likely the cause of the `variants` entry there in your `.rosinstall` file.

With the following command:

```
rosinstall_generator --deps --tar --rosdistro=crystal ros_core
```

That specific entry becomes:

```
- tar:
    local-name: variants/ros_core
    uri: https://github.com/ros2-gbp/variants-release/archive/release/crystal/ros_core/0.6.1-0.tar.gz
    version: variants-release-release-crystal-ros_core-0.6.1-0
```

Which would cause the `ros_core` package to be placed in your workspace. That makes sense: you asked for `ros_core` *and* its dependencies.

By specifying `--upstream-development`, `rosinstall_generator` has no choice but to add an entry for the entire source repository containing `ros_core` (as that is the package you asked the `.rosinstall` file to be generated for), resulting in all metapackages defining ROS 2 variants to be placed in your workspace (as they are all hosted in the `variants` repository). This then results in `rosdep` trying to install dependencies for all those variants.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William Bulle](https://answers.ros.org/users/40424/william-bulle/) on 2019-04-02**:
Oh it makes sense that `rosdep` tries to download the dependencies for `ros_base` and `desktop`.
But ultimately it failed to `apt-get install` as they don't exist or it doesn't manage to locate them. How come ?

I generated my `.install` with

```
rosinstall_generator ros_core --rosdistro crystal --upstream-development --deps > ros2_core.install
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:
I'm confused: you're ok with those additional dependencies?

**Comment by [William Bulle](https://answers.ros.org/users/40424/william-bulle/) on 2019-04-02**:
I specified `--upstream-development` as I wanted to have some upstream package in order to use the `-DFORCE_BUILD_VENDOR_PKG=ON` as I want to minimize the number of dependencies on my target.

They seems to not be useful in what I'm trying to do but I wanted to know why it fails to locate the packages. My guess is they don't exist for armhf but in this case, rosdep would fail to resolve any ros dependencies in the case of my ros file install being incomplete.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:\

> should rosdep have a option to ignore all ros packages and just download built dependencies ?

ROS pkgs can be build dependencies as well, so such an option would need to discriminate between ROS pkgs and *system* dependencies in that case.

If you need only certain pkgs newer than the released version, perhaps those could be added manually to the file (you can always add an additional entry to the `.rosinstall` file by hand, it's a simple yaml list).

Can you perhaps restate/reformulate your question? Your initial question seemed to be:

> i would like to understand why rosdep is trying to find and install these dependencies, not necessary according to ROS REP 2001 ?

The answer to that is: you're adding `--upstream-development` to `rosinstall_generator` and it downloads the entire `variants` repository, which contains manifests for *all* ROS 2 variants, hence the additional deps.

you're now asking "why it fails to locate the packages".

Perhaps that should be a new question.